# Could not initialize class jmeter HTTPHC4Impl

Tags: api, testing, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

When I try to run my api test on jmeter, this error occurs: `Uncaught Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl in thread Thread[Thread Group 1-10,6,main]. See log file for details` How can I solve it?

Comment: Did you check jmeter.log for exception?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your JMeter installation got corrupt somehow, double check that you have [`ApacheJMeter_http.jar`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jmeter/ApacheJMeter_http) file under "lib/ext" folder of your JMeter installation and the .jar file contains the needed class.

If the .jar is not there I would recommend either downloading the appropriate version from the above website or install/reinstall `jmeter - HTTP Protocol Support` plugin using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/)

[image]

Comment: I noticed there is an error when start jemter: `SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.`

Comment: Also after I put `jmeter-plugins-manager-1.3.jar` to `/usr/local/Cellar/jmeter/5.2.1/libexec/lib`, start jemeter, I cannot find the plugin manager in the `option` of GUI